# How to set a specific website as the google homepage instead of the normal google search bar?

Tags: google-chrome

Everytime I access Google Chrome, I basically want to be able to open up a specific page each time. For example, if I wanted to open up Bing instead of google as the homepage, how would I be able to do that on chrome? I tried changing the settings around for startup, but if I were to close google chrome, then that page would not show up again. I mean one alternative would be to set the homepage button or a continue where you left off but I would rather have it that chrome open up specifically to my page. Is this possible in chrome? 
I guess for some context, I am using Chrome OS (Chromebits as my computer).

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings (Right side hamburger menu) > search > type "On Startup" > open a specific page > "Http:// what ever you want".
This is not the eight place to ask this type of question.

Comment: No, thats not what I mean. I know that method but anytime that I say open up a new tab or open up a new google chrome page there should be a certain page showing up.